# Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get error :

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Code:

```
string connetionString = null;

SqlConnection connection;
SqlCommand command;

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

XmlReader xmlFile;
string sql = null;

connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD";

connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

connection.Open();

SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Seamen(PersonalIdentityNumber) VALUES (@PersonalIdentityNumber))", connection);

foreach (var P in PersonalIdentityNumber)
{
    command1.Parameters.Clear();
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", P);

    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

connection.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

I get this error at runtime, so don't know where it occurs, all I know is that it happens in that code above. Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: `values(@PersonalIdentityNumber))` you have an extra `)`

Comment: In the sqlcommand you have an extra `)`

Comment: removes the last `)`

Comment: People downvote your question because you do not mention that this is a SqlException. Usually it is a good Idea to provide full Exception-Details when asking Questions. `i get error` is not much detail.

Also make sure you dont put hardcoreded details like Passwords and usernames into the code samples. Make sure to remove them before asking. (I did this for you)

Comment: I down-voted because the question is "not useful" (one of the reasons to down vote if you hover your cursor over the down vote button) and I also voted to close the question because it's "a simple typographical error" (one of the built-in reasons to close).

Answer (score 4):

This part is wrong:

```
"INSERT INTO Seamen(PersonalIdentityNumber) values(@PersonalIdentityNumber))"
```

it should be

```
"INSERT INTO Seamen(PersonalIdentityNumber) values(@PersonalIdentityNumber)"
```

Notice the last bracket.

Comment: Do any of the downvoters care to explain their reasons?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Seamen(PersonalIdentityNumber) values(@PersonalIdentityNumber))", connection);
```

should be:

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Seamen(PersonalIdentityNumber) values(@PersonalIdentityNumber)", connection);
```

Note the missing bracket at the end of your SQL.

Generally speaking, you may want to improve your database handling code. It would be better with a few `using` blocks.